# OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Unauthorized for omniauth-twitter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, localhost, omniauth

When I click on [http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter], I am getting OAuth::Unauthorized
401 Unauthorized error in rails. I am following Railscast video #241 for Twitter authentication with my rails application. I have googled a lot for it but could not find answer for it.

```
 Info regarding app on twitter:
 Callback URL: [http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback]
 Website: [http://127.0.0.1:3000]


### omniauth.rb 
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  # provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
  provider :twitter, ENV['75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA'],    ENV['GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A']
end

### routes.rb
Chilli::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  #match '/auth/:twitter/callback' => 'sessions#create', :as => :auth_callback
  match 'auth/twitter/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
end

### application.html.erb
<div id="user_nav">
<%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter"%>
</div>

### sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in."
  end
end

### user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Did you check your application settings at twitter.com? Make sure you have any URL as a callback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `omniauth.rb` what is
`ENV['75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA'],    ENV['GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A']`?

If `75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA` and `GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A` are your `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET` then it should be written as:

```
provider :twitter, '75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA', 'GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A'
```

Comment: @varunvlalan, I tired with your suggestion, but getting same error.Do not know what to do?

Comment: One more thing I noticed in _routes.rb_
`match 'auth/twitter/callback', to: 'sessions#create'`

Prepend path with "/".
`match '/auth/twitter/callback', to: 'sessions#create'`

Comment: @VSiingh what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what fixed my issue was:

Changing:

```
ENV['75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA'],ENV['GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A']
```

to:

```
'75UOAIDmKrRXvXKBhNvKA', 'GrIaBI0tQy2TtjOtaFL9VxT6s9qq1sV7h9yRaZW4A'
```

and putting a '/' before 'auth' here:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: 'get'
match '/auth/failure', to: redirect('/'), via: 'get'
```